# Android - XML - Image - Retrieve

Tags: android, xml, image, xml-parsing, drawable

Hello i am trying to parse an xml file whereby i am retrieving the following files:

```
<questions>      
   <question
        number="3"
        text="Have you ever milked a cow?"
        imageUrl="http://www.google.com/quiz/Questions/q3.png" />
</questions>
```

I have no problem in getting the necessary data from the xml file. Now the problem that i am facing is that i want to get the image loaded from the xml file itself but now instead of getting it remotely, i will be getting it from the drawable folder.

I have tried to use the following code but it does not seem to be working. Perhaps i should be using another command rather than the imagesrc to get the image from the drawable folder.The code that i have been trying is aas follows:

```
<questions>
    <question
        number="1"
        text="This shows the turn left sign"
        imagesrc="R.drawable.quizicon" />
</questions>
```

Thank you for your precious help.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void startElement(String namespaceURI, String localName, String qName, 
        Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
    if (localName.equals("question")) {
          System.out.println("The value of attribute 'imageUrl' is: " + atts.getValue("imageUrl"));
    }   
}
```

Comment: What i am needing here is to find a way to get the path of the image from the xml file itself but not from the java ones.thank you

Comment: Artyom is telling you that you need to parse your XML file, in this case using an SAXParser. From there you can retrieve the `imageUrl` attribute, and using `getIdentifier()` from the Resources class, extract the correct drawable identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`getIdentifier`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

Other alternatives are to use a lookup table in your application, or use the `assets/` folder instead of bundled drawables.

Comment: you mean that instead of using the drawable folder assets would be correct if i use the following commands:
<questions>
    <question
        number="1"
        text="This shows the turn left sign"
        imagesrc="/assets/quizicon" />
</questions>